# Quarkus finds 0 tests to run

Tags: java, junit, quarkus

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my Quarkus app. My configuration seems fine. However, Quarkus is not finding my tests.

To run the tests, I run `./gradlew quarkusDev` and then press the `[r]` key. This is the output I get:

```
Starting test run, 0 tests to run.
Running 1/0. Running: #JUnit Jupiter
```

My test is located at `src/test/java/br.com.org.product.reports.service/ExampleTest.java`. This is the test:

```java
package br.com.org.product.reports.service;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@QuarkusTest
class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void example() {
        assertEquals(1 + 1, 2);
    }
}
```

These are the relevant parts of my `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
    id 'jacoco'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Any ideas on why my test is not being found? If I generate a new Quarkus project from scratch, the tests run fine. The generated configuration looks exactly like the one I have right now. However, I can't re-generate the project, I need to fix this one.

Comment: do you really have a folder called `br.com.org.product.reports.service` in `src/test/java`?